# Rotate shape fill without rotating shape in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have been looking for a way to do this for quite some time and I came up short.

I did read all the articles I could find but all of them seem to be focused on how to rotate the shape without rotating the image.

I am automatically adding a shape to be the same size as my selected range and filling that shape with the image selected with `msoFileDialogFilePicker`

```
    With shp.fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture strFilePath
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoFalse
    End With
```

While for me, the more logical way is, if I placed a rectangle and I fill it with an image, maybe the image orientation is not correct or I want to straighten the image so I want to be able to rotate only the image fill without rotating the shape itself.

> At this moment I am using 1 button to open the image in paint using
> Shell, and another button to refresh the image fill once I have
> manually rotated my image in Paint.

Is there a way to do this in VBA? Or am I missing something...

Comment: Before inserting the content to be rotated, rotate the shape exactly the amount to be rotated in the opposite direction. Then insert the filling and rotate the shape back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found to be a decent user experience, is adding a button "Open in Paint" and allow the user to manipulate the image in paint however they desire, after the image has been manipulated (in my case rotated) and saved, I just refresh the source of the image (either by a "refresh" button or automatically when my sheet regains "focus") and the changes are reflected inside my shape.